# How to search with comma separated string in multiple column

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called TABLE_1 which has following columns:

```
 id   phone_number user_name  country state
```

I want to search with this string " 1, 948583848, akash, usa,calfornia". How do I write a mysql query to get result form above Phone TABLE_1?

Comment: For hint...
We do search queyr through the FULL_TEXT_SEARCH in mysql and with LIKE. But in FULL_TEXT_SEARCH it never search for less then 3 character string... and like will search one column at one time... I want to search on all column with comma seperated string.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the `where` clause that you want?

```
where concat_ws(', ', id, phone_number, user_name, country, state) = '1, 948583848, akash, usa,calfornia'
```

This seems like a very strange requirement.  You are better off doing individual comparisons on the columns rather than concatenating the values together.

Comment: good hint but not working actually... it is returning empty result..